# python ordereddict or OrderedDict?

Tags: python, pyyaml

I'm so confused right now. I'm using PyYAML for editing some YAML files.

```
data = yaml.load_all(open('testingyaml.yaml'),Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)
```

My testingyaml.yaml file contains the following content:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/nfvgrid
dns:
  enable: false
cassandra:
  host: 192.168.7.151
```

When I print data it prints the following:

`ordereddict([('spring', ordereddict([('profiles', 'dev'), ('datasource', ordereddict([('url', 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/nfvgrid')]))])), ('dns', ordereddict([('enable', False)])), ('cassandra', ordereddict([('host', '192.168.7.151')]))])`

I further want to perform some operations on this ordered dictionary but python throws an error `NameError: name 'ordereddict' is not defined`

It's usually `OrderedDict` but somehow PyYAML returns ordereddict. 
How should I solve this issue?

Comment: Could it be possible it converts everything to lowercase?

Comment: What do you get when you do `type(data)`? My guess is that pyYaml is using some dictionary type of its own, not `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: Is this `pyyaml`, or `ruamel.yaml`?

Comment: I was mixing ruamel.yaml and pyyaml. Got it all sorted out now! 
Using simple pyYaml load_all() and it returns data of type "dict" which solves my problem. Thanks a lot for the quick response everyone. Saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost certainly not using `pyyaml` as stated, as it does not have a `RoundTripLoader`.  Instead you are probably using [`ruamel.yaml`](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml).

This alternative uses its own [`ruamel.ordereddict`](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/ordereddict) on python 2 installations, and the native `collections.OrderedDict` on python 3.  This alternative supports most operations that OrderedDict does so there is no reason you cannot manipulate it.  See its documentation.

However, if you wish to convert from one to the other, you could do something like:

```
x = collections.OrderedDict(some_ruamel_ordered_dict.items())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it all sorted out now. Going with the basic pyYaml load_all() method and getting the desired output for further processing.

Answer (score 2):

There is something strange going on, or you are not using the code example to load that file and then get that print from `data`. If you are really using `yaml.load_all` that will give you back a generator object which allows you to step over the 1 or more YAML document in that file. Since you're not using [document directive markers](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#marker/directives%20end/), it makes little sense to use `load_all()`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import ruamel.yaml as yaml

datas = yaml.load_all(open('testingyaml.yaml'), Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)
print(datas, '\n', '-' * 50, sep='')
for data in datas:
    print(data['spring']['profiles'])
print(type(data))
```

gives:
    
    dev
The actual type of data in the above example is a `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap` which is also what you would get if you did the simpler:

```
data = yaml.load(open('testingyaml.yaml'), Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)
print(type(data))
```

which prints `<class 'ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap'>` (not the use of `load()` instead of `loadall()`.

The `CommentedMap` is derived from `ordereddict`

```
from ruamel.yaml.compat import ordereddict
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap
assert issubclass(CommentedMap, ordereddict)
```

because for roundtripping (you are using the `RoundTripLoader`) `ruamel.yaml` needs to preserve the order and have a place to attach any comments and other informations to preserve, which is not possible when using `dict`. `ordereddict` is a just a convenience class around `ruamel.ordereddict` (if available) or `OrderedDict` ¹.

You can of course import `ordereddict` yourself as above and use it, but if you don't need roundtripping nor preservation of order in your dictionaries (i.e. are fine with `dict`) just use the standard loader:

```
data = yaml.load(open('testingyaml.yaml'))
print(type(data))
```

prints:

```
<type 'dict'>
```

I recommend not to "downgrade" by using PyYAML: it only implements the old 1.1 version of YAML, and although ruamel.yaml is a derivative of PyYAML, since it was derived, it has quite a few issues solved that originally wer filed against, and still pertain to, PyYAML ².

---

¹ <sub>ruamel.ordereddict is a (fast) C implementation of ordered dicts that existed already for a few years before OrderedDict appeared in the standard library, as the standard library version has a small subset of functionality, and until Python 3.5 was (slow) pure Python, switching to OrderedDict was never really an option for me.</sub>
² <sub>But then I am biased as I am the author of `ruamel.yaml` (and know that it needs more documentation).</sub>